# Logic to implement late fine for school ERP

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, winforms

I need to implement late fine in Educational ERP.
Suppose a due date is set for each installment and if student pay fee after that due that so fine will imposed like as 1$ per day after duedate.

e.g. - Due date For January installment is 31 January if a student pay on 10 of Feb . so late fine 10$ will be imposed on January installment for 10 days late.

Please suggest me logic to implement it.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know why you got the down-votes.... Check my answer....

Comment: Please don't down vote new users.some users are just down vote eager

Answer (score 1):

```
int fine = (int)(new DateTime(2016, 2, 10) - new DateTime(2016, 1, 31)).TotalDays;
```

Or in other words...

```
int fine = (int)(<PaymentDate> - <DueDate>).TotalDays;
```

Comment: I have already done it but problem is there that if a student having 100+10(late fine)=110 due with late fine for January instalment but he deposit only 100 then after deposit , balance will become 0 for January hence late fine is not calculated further because we are showing late fine virtually , once student submit late fine they we make transaction in database, if student only pay instalment amount hence further late fine will not calculated even student deposit after due date.